# How to update md-select options when scope value changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a very basic `md-select` element with only 3 options. I allow a user to select multiple options via the `multiple` attribute.

I have a button that removes the second value, only if it is selected. The value is removed correctly from the scope variable, although the changes are not applied to the `md-select` element?

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.selectedNumbers = [];

$scope.numbers = [{
   num: 1
}, {
   num: 2
}, {
   num: 3
}];

$scope.deselectTwo = function() {        
  if ($scope.selectedNumbers.indexOf(2) > -1) {          
     $scope.selectedNumbers.splice(1, 1);
  }
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>Numbers</label>
  <md-select ng-model="selectedNumbers" multiple>
    <md-option ng-repeat="number in numbers" ng-value="{{number.num}}">
      {{number.num}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>

<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="deselectTwo()">
  Deselect 2
</md-button>

<div>
  Ng-repeat for '$scope.selectedNumbers':
  <span ng-repeat="number in selectedNumbers">
    {{number}}
  </span>
</div>
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWNrjB?editors=101)**

To replicate the issue, select "1" and "2" from the dropdown. Then click the "Deselect 2" button to see it removed from the ng-repeat, but not from the selected options in the dropdown.

How can I update my `md-select` options when the scope variable is changed?

Comment: Strange - could this be a bug with `md-select`? I've noticed that if you replace the `splice()` with an assignment (e.g. `$scope.selectedNumbers = [1]`) then it works as expected.

Comment: @cmrn - Hmmm, interesting find. I might have to submit a bug report on the Angular Material github.

Comment: As an ugly workaround, you could add a line to set `selectedNumbers` to a copy of itself, which causes `md-select` to update. e.g: `$scope.selectedNumbers = $scope.selectedNumbers.slice();`

Comment: @cmrn - Sounds good, will run with that for the time being since it fixes the problem :)

Comment: Great - in that case I've posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange - could this be a bug with `md-select`? I've noticed that if you replace the `splice()` with an assignment (e.g. `$scope.selectedNumbers = [1]`) then it works as expected.

As an ugly workaround, you could add a line to set selectedNumbers to a copy of itself, which causes `md-select` to update. e.g: `$scope.selectedNumbers = $scope.selectedNumbers.slice();`

Keen to hear if anyone else has a better answer!

Comment: Marking as accepted since it does technically answer the question. Thanks Cmrn. Will post here once I hear back from the Angular Material team on Github.